# A Geometrical Interpretation of the line integral of $f$ along $C$ with respect to $x$ and $y$.

Tags: calculus

I'm studying the line integral of a function along a curve $C$ with respect to $x$.
Is the assertion as the following figure indicated true or false?

I have read the questions
[Interpreting Line Integrals with Respect to $x$ or $y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116387/interpreting-line-integrals-with-respect-to-x-or-y)
and
[Interpretation of a line integral with respect to x or y .](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080027/interpretation-of-a-line-integral-with-respect-to-x-or-y)
But I am dissatisfied the answer.

And we can't give a geometrical interpretation of the line integral with respect to $y$ in this case because the direct of $y$ back and forth when $t$ increase.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said the curve back and forth in $y$ direction. Let's assume the curve $C$ does not have that little twist in $x$ direction at the beginning. This means the curve $C$ is a function of $x$.

Then the line integral with respect to $x$ would be
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x,y(x))\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}\,dx$$

where $\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}\,dx$ is the infinitesimal arc length of each subinterval. So it is exactly as in the picture.

Now for the $y$ direction, since $C$ is not really a function in this direction, we have to separate it into parts. In this case, we have three parts $C_1,C_2,C_3$, as shown below

[image]

On each subcurve, we can do the same thing as before:

$$\int_{y_1}^{y_2} f(x(y),y)\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2}\,dy$$

where $\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2}\,dy$ is the arc length of an subinterval.

Comment: The definition given of line integral wrt to x does not seem to agree with the one given in Stewart Calculus, which doesn't include the square root term before dx. Also, even if the definition is correct, the answer doesn't give any meaningful geometric interpretation, as requested by the OP